Filter organization does not carry over to new dashboard tabs
Using Spotfire Analyst 14.0.1 HF-004
I had created a dashboard and enabled filters. I added the filters to a filter schema, and organized the filters into nice groups.
When I create a new dashboard tab, and select to use the filter schema, the current filtering selected appears on the new dashboard ... but the filter organization does not.
Is it possible to save the filter organization as well as the filter selected data?


OK. I figured it out.

Be on the page (dashboard) with the current filter organization you prefer.
Right click towards the bottom of the filters sidebar to get a menu...

Select "Apply Filter Organization"
In the pop-up window, select the page you want to apply the organization TO...

The filter organization should appear on the page (dashboard) selected.

